# How to capture/record the rating (stars) in vugen/load runner

Tags: loadrunner, blazemeter, vugen

Does anyone have experience doing a load test on ratings? I've tried to test the load on some e-commerce site on rating a few items but vugen does not record the event.

Comment: Do you work for IEEE.ORG or have permission to performance test their website?  (See license agreement)

Comment: Does it matter? If it is an open site to rate robots, I would like to test it. If you're hesitant then can you please tell me if you can do rating on yelp.com hotels?

Comment: Peformance testing tools include license provisions that you do not use the tools to test sites that you do not own, manage, control or have permission from those that do have those rights.  Otherwise you are engaging in a denial of service attack without the permission of the owner of the site.  In addition, many sites have additional license provisions which restrict the use of automated tools to access the site services to those published and supported by the site provider. No more

Comment: Running a performance testing tool against someone else's site without coordination or permission is no different than getting a shiny new shotgun for a holiday gift, then driving around and shooting people's postal boxes....just because you can.    Do not point your tactical destructive software at software you do not own, manage, control or have explicit written permission from those who do and where you have coordinated actions as a part of your testing

Comment: And no, you do not point these tools at Yelp either.  Unless you work for Yelp and you have their permission to do so.

Comment: I've edited the question @James. Can I get the answer if you know it?

Comment: I am not interested in supporting this behavior as it damages the reputation of the performance testing profession

Comment: This question is just to record the rating through Vugen, not to do a stress test on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried recording this. But i think you can record this if you enable **Download Non-HTML resources** in recording options of Vugen. Try recording in both HTML mode and URL mode.
If still it is not recording, the final option is to use Trueclient protocol of HP Loadrunner